# Task.WaitAll() is not working for the second set of task array

Tags: multithreading

I am new to threading and I have currently used Tasks to perform multi threading. As you can see in the code, one set of tasks perform a series of extraction from an Excel and the `Task.WaitAll()` is working as expected.

But for the second set of tasks, the `Task.WaitAll()` is not working as expected. The control is going directly to the next method outside the task pool instead of waiting for the tasks to complete.

I am using the first set of tasks to extract from an Excel and the next set of tasks to store the values in objects.

Thanks in advance.

**//MainClass.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
/// <summary>
/// class to call the methods to extract values and assign values using multithreading
/// </summary>
public class MainClass : ExtractValues
{
    public static int size;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ExtractValues objectOfExtractValues = new ExtractValues();
        Values objectOfValues = new Values();
        size = objectOfExtractValues.initialize();
        List<int> Range = new List<int>();
        Range = objectOfExtractValues.cellRangeFinder();


        //creating a new task to call methods to extract details from the excel to run parallelly 
        Task[] task = new Task[6];
        {
            task[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfExtractValues.thread1(Range[0]));


            task[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfExtractValues.thread2(Range[0], Range[1]));
            task[2] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfExtractValues.thread3(Range[2], Range[3]));
            task[3] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfExtractValues.thread4(Range[4], Range[5]));
            task[4] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfExtractValues.thread5(Range[6], Range[7]));
            task[5] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfExtractValues.thread6(Range[8], Range[9]));

        }
        Task.WaitAll(task);
        objectOfValues.init();



        Task tasknew1 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfValues.assignValues1());
        Task tasknew2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfValues.assignValues2());
        Task tasknew3 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfValues.assignValues3());
        Task tasknew4 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfValues.assignValues4());
        Task tasknew5 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfValues.assignValues5());
        Task tasknew6 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfValues.assignValues6());
        Task tasknew7 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => objectOfValues.assignValues7());



        Task.WaitAll(tasknew1, tasknew2, tasknew3, tasknew4, tasknew5, tasknew6, tasknew7);
        //Task.WhenAll();
        //Task.WaitAll();
        //calling method to initialize the object array



        // creating another task to call methods to assign details stored in the list to objects parallelly 

        objectOfExtractValues.endProcess();

        // wait



        Console.ReadLine();
        objectOfValues.show();
    }
}
}
```

** ExtractValue.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

 namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
/// <summary>
/// class containing methods to extract values from the excel
/// </summary>
public class ExtractValues 
{
 public int rowCount;

    public int colCount;

    //lists to store values from different sections of the excel
    public static List<int> rangeList = new List<int>();
    public static List<string> tempList = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> tempList2 = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> tempList3 = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> tempList4 = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> tempList5 = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> tempList6 = new List<string>();
    public static List<string> tempList7 = new List<string>();
    string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;




    Excel.Application xlApp;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
    Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet;
    Excel.Range xlRange;
    int start, end;

    /// <summary>
    /// method to initaialize the excel and get the column and row count
    /// </summary>
    public int initialize()
    {
        var dir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(path);
        string location = dir + "\\some.xlsx";
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(location);
        xlWorksheet = xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        rowCount = xlWorksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

        colCount = xlWorksheet.Columns.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.Count;



        return colCount;

    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  method to read from the excel file and print it. method reads the rows until the count passed to it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="count"></param>
    public void thread1(int count)
    {


        for (int i = 2; i <colCount; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 1; j < count; j++)
            {
                if (xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value == null && xlRange.Cells[j + 1, i].Value != null)
                {
                    tempList.Add(" ");
                }


                if (xlRange.Cells[j, i] != null && xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value != null )

                    tempList.Add(xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value.ToString());


            }

        }

        // for loop to read the cardpan row
        for (int i = 2; i <= colCount; i++)
        {

            for (int j = 12; j <= 12; j++)
            {

                if (xlRange.Cells[j, i] != null && xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value != null)

                    tempList7.Add(xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value.ToString());


            }

        }
   }




    /// <summary>
    ///  method to read from the excel file and print it. method reads the rows from and until the count passed to it.
    /// </summary>
    public void thread2(int count1, int count2)
    {



        for (int i = 2; i <= colCount; i++)
        {

            for (int j = count1; j <=count2; j++)
            {

                if (xlRange.Cells[j, i] != null && xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value != null)

                    tempList2.Add(xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value.ToString());


            }

        }



    }


    /// <summary>
    ///  method to read from the excel file and print it. method reads the rows from and until the count passed to it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="count1"></param>
    /// <param name="count2"></param>
    public void thread3(int count1, int count2)
    {

        for (int i = 2; i <= colCount; i++)
        {

            for (int j = count1; j <= count2; j++)
            {

                if (xlRange.Cells[j, i] != null && xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value != null)

                    tempList3.Add(xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value.ToString());


            }

        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///  method to read from the excel file and print it. method reads the rows from and until the count passed to it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="count1"></param>
    /// <param name="count2"></param>
    public void thread4(int count1, int count2)
    {



        for (int i = 2; i <= colCount; i++)
        {

            for (int j = count1; j <= count2; j++)
            {
                if (xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value == null && xlRange.Cells[j + 1, i].Value == null)
                {
                    tempList4.Add(" ");
                    break;
                }


                if (xlRange.Cells[j, i] != null && xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value != null)

                    tempList4.Add(xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value.ToString());


            }

        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///  method to read from the excel file and print it. Method reads the rows from and until the count passed to it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="count1"></param>
    /// <param name="count2"></param>
    public void thread5(int count1, int count2)
    {



        for (int i = 2; i <= colCount; i++)
        {

            for (int j = count1; j <= count2; j++)
            {
                if (xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value == null && xlRange.Cells[j + 1, i].Value == null)
                {
                    tempList5.Add(" ");
                    break;
                }

                if (xlRange.Cells[j, i] != null && xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value != null)

                    tempList5.Add(xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value.ToString());

                //add useful things here!   
            }

        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    ///  method to read from the excel file and print it. method reads the rows from and till the count passed to it.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="count1"></param>
    /// <param name="count2"></param>
    public void thread6(int count1, int count2)
    {
        for (int i = 2; i <= colCount; i++)
        {

            for (int j = count1; j <= count2; j++)
            {
                if (xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value == null && xlRange.Cells[j + 1, i].Value == null)
                {
                    tempList6.Add(" ");
                    break;
                }


                if (xlRange.Cells[j, i] != null && xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value != null)

                    tempList6.Add(xlRange.Cells[j, i].Value.ToString());

            }

        }
    }




    /// <summary>
    /// method to end the excel file operations
    /// </summary>
    public void endProcess()
    {

        xlWorkbook.Close();


        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();


        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);


        //close and release

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

        //quit and release
        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);


    }

    /// <summary>
    /// method to find the merged cells in the excel and store their starting and ending cell values in a list
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public List<int> cellRangeFinder()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {

            for (int k = 1; k <=1 ; k++)
            {
                if (xlRange.Cells[i, k] != null && xlRange.Cells[i+1, k].Value == null)
                {


                    start = i;
                    int tempCounter = i + 1;
                    while(xlRange.Cells[tempCounter, k].Value == null && (tempCounter<=rowCount+3))
                    {
                        tempCounter++;
                    }
                    end = tempCounter-1;

                    rangeList.Add(start);
                    rangeList.Add(end);
                    i = tempCounter-1;


                }
            }
        }
        return rangeList;

    }
}
}
```

**Values.cs**

```
enter code here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

 namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
/// <summary>
/// Class to store the values in the objects
/// </summary>
public class Values : MainClass
{
    // Variables to store the values of each object
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string tType { get; set; }
    public string cType { get; set; }
    public string tName { get; set; }
    public string SNumber { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string objective { get; set; }
    public string reference { get; set; }
    public string prerequisite { get; set; }
    public string procedure { get; set; }
    public string cPan { get; set; }
    public string amount { get; set; }
    public string pHost { get; set; }
    public string pCard { get; set; }
    public string cSlip { get; set; }
    // Declaring the Values' class object array
    Values[] list;

    /// <summary>
    /// method  to set the size of the array object 
    /// </summary>
    public void init()
    {
         list= new Values[size];

    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Method to assign the values of the first temp list into the object array
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size"> size varaible is to check the creating of new objects</param>
    public void assignValues1()
    {


        int m = 0;

       list[m] = new Values();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList.Count();)
        {

            list[m].ID = Convert.ToInt32(tempList[i]);
            list[m].tType = tempList[i + 1];
            list[m].cType = tempList[i + 2];
            list[m].tName = tempList[i + 3];
            list[m].SNumber = tempList[i + 4];
            list[m].title = tempList[i + 5];
            list[m].objective = tempList[i + 6];
            list[m].reference = tempList[i + 7];
            list[m].prerequisite = tempList[i + 8];

            i = i + 9;
            m++;
            if (m < size)
                list[m] = new Values();
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to assign the values of the sevent temp list into the object array which contains Card Pan
    /// </summary>

    public void assignValues2()
    {
        int m = 0;
        list[m] = new Values();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList7.Count();)
        {
            list[m].cPan = tempList7[i];
            i = i + 1;
            m++;
            if (m < size)
                list[m] = new Values();
            else
                break;
        }



    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to assign the values of the second temp list into the object array which contains the procedure
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size"> size varaible is to check the creating of new objects</param>
    public void assignValues3()
    {
        int m = 0;
        list[m] = new Values();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList2.Count();)
        {
            list[m].procedure = tempList2[i] + tempList2[i+1];
            i = i + 2;
            m++;
            if (m < size)
                list[m] = new Values();
            else
                break;
        }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to assign the values of the amount temp list into the object array which contains amount values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size"> size varaible is to check the creating of new objects</param>
    public void assignValues4()
    {
        int m = 0;
        list[m] = new Values();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList3.Count();)
        {
            list[m].amount = tempList3[i];
            i = i + 1;
            m++;
            if (m < size)
                list[m] = new Values();
            else
                break;
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Method to assign the values of the fourth list into the object array which contains phost values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size"> size varaible is to check the creating of new objects</param>
    public void assignValues5()
    {
        int m = 0;
        int i = 0;
        list[m] = new Values();
        for (i = 0; i < tempList4.Count();i++)
        {
            while (tempList4[i] != " " )
            {

                list[m].pHost = tempList4[i];
                i++;
            }
            if (tempList4[i] == " " && i + 1 < tempList5.Count() && tempList4[i + 1] == " ")
            {
                m++;
                i++;
                list[m] = new Values();
                list[m].pHost = tempList4[i];

            }
                m++;

            if (m < size)
                list[m] = new Values();
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to assign the values of the fifth temp list into the object array which contains pCard values
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size"> size varaible is to check the creating of new objects</param>
    public void assignValues6()
    {
        int m = 0;
        int m2 = 0;
        list[m] = new Values();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList5.Count() ; i++)
        {
            while (tempList5[i] != " ")
            {

                list[m].pCard = tempList5[i];
                i++;
            }

            if (tempList5[i] == " " && i + 1 < tempList5.Count() && tempList5[i + 1] == " ")
            {
                if (m == m2 && m + 1 < size)
                {
                    m++;
                    m2 = m;
                }
                list[m] = new Values();
                list[m].pCard = " ";
                m++;
                if (m < size)
                    continue;
                else
                    break;
            }

            m++;
            m2 = m; 
            if (m < size)
                list[m] = new Values();
            else
                break;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to assign the values of the sixth temp list into the object array which contains the cslip details
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="size"> size varaible is to check the creating of new objects</param>
    public void assignValues7()
    {
        int m = 0;
        int m2 = 0;
        list[m] = new Values();
        for (int i = 0; i < tempList6.Count();)
        {
            while (tempList6[i] != " ")
            {

                list[m].cslip = tempList6[i];
                i++;
            }

            if (tempList6[i] == " " && i + 1 < tempList6.Count() && tempList6[i + 1] == " ")
            {
                if (m == m2 && m + 1 < size)
                {
                    m++;
                    m2 = m;
                }
                list[m].cSlip = " ";
                m++;
                if (m < size)
                    continue;
                else
                    break;
            }

            m++;
            m2 = m;
            if (m < size)
                list[m] = new Values();
            else
                break;
        }
    }


    public void show()
    {
       for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(list[i].ID + " " + list[i].tName);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Which thread calls  Task.WaitAll?

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Did you mean to ask which task array I am calling a wait on? or which thread I have assigned for the tasks?

Comment: I am asking, which thread is actually waits fot task/tasknew arrays (by calling WaitAll)? Is it the UI thread? Dedicated thread?

Comment: It's a dedicated thread. I am using console application for the above code.

Comment: The code looks fine, it seems like, that no one waits for the waiting thread. For instance, if you run it in console applciation, Main method -  your console application process is ended before the waited threads ends, if you simple add Console.ReadLine() at the end of your code - you'll get all the waited threads tasks done...

Comment: Another thing, if you run it in Console Application Main method, you run it on main thread - not a dedicated one.

Comment: Okay. So creating a task does not mean it's a dedicated thread?  In the code, for the first set of Task, I.e, Task[] task = new Task[6] , when the Task.WaitAll(task) is called. The control waits till all the tasks have been executed before moving to the next line of code. This is not happening for the second set of tasks i.e, Task[] tasknew = new Task[7];

Comment: If you run it in Console Application Main method you won't wait for the first array either. try adding Task.Dellay in one of your tasks, and see if you get your work done

Comment: Creating a task doesn't mean it's a dedicated thread - it uses ThreadPiool. ThreadPool reuses thread for performance reasons. You can create two tasks which will run on the same thread...What I've asked you about is the waiting thread (for the newly created task - it can be a dedicated thread/task/ui thread/.... The thread which actually waits for your tasks, if no one waits for him (like the scenario when the process is finished) no one will wait for his waiting task either. Since that thread is dead already

Comment: Task.Delay is not working :(

Comment: What do you mean not working? The code with Task.Delay isn't woking?

Comment: Just add Console.ReadLine at the end...

Comment: I want the tasks to wait till they complete because i want to call another method after the tasks. This method is dependent on the completion of the tasks. Using task.delay in the task has not helped either.

Comment: You just need to call objectOfValues.show(); before waiting for Console.ReadLine();

Answer (score 0):

Your code is written OK, it seems that there is an issue with the thread that waits for all your tasks to be done ( Task.WaitAll call on tasks/tasknew arrays).

For instance, if you'll run your code from ConsoleApplciation in Main function, your process will end way before your tasks. So, simple Console.ReadLine call will solve your issue in this specific case.

Something like this:

```
 Task[] task = new Task[6];
    {
    ///...

    Task.WaitAll(task);

    Task[] tasknew = new Task[7];
    {
        //...
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasknew);
    //This will prevant you process to be closed, since it will wait for keyboard input.
    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I want the control to wait till the tasks have completed because i want to call another method after the tasks. This method is dependent on the completion of the tasks. I tried using Task.delay and using console.readLine(). But the control starts the tasks and moves on to the next methods.

Comment: You just need to call objectOfValues.show(); before waiting for Console.ReadLine();

Comment: I am planning to add more methods after the tasks in the MainClass.cs, not just the show() method. And I need those methods to execute only after the tasks have been completed. I tried using Parallel.invoke(). That didn't work either.

Comment: You need to understand that you cannot accomplish what you are telling here if your process exits. You can create a dedicated Task,which will wait for all of your awaited Task...

Comment: Hey Pavel, I found out what was wrong. Actually nothing was wrong, the tasks were executing so fast that I thought they were moving on to the next method without completing. It took a while before I realised this. The assignvalues() methods had a problem and I got confused because of that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Still, you aren't actually waiting for your tasks, if one of your task will take time to execute, you won't be awaiting it - that's why Task.Delay didn't work..